# Update only div panel on button click in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there functionality in RoR to create dynamic panels within a RoR website?  What I am trying to accomplish in the main page is to be able to update a panel with a click of a navigation button instead of loading up an entirely new page.

**Located in Pages View**

Here I want to load new content in my `dynamicLoadingPanel` with a button click in the `navButton` span in my `home.html.erb`:

```
<span id="navButton" class="button">Content2</span>
<div id="dynamicLoadingPanel"></div>
```

The page I want to show in the `dynamicLoadingPanel` is the `_categoryOne.html.erb` file also located under the Pages View folder.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other answers said, you will want to use ajax.  Rails has some nice ajax integration with jquery now, via the jquery_ujs.js file and gem.  You should start by installing this gem and running the generators that the readme mentions: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

There's 4-5 steps to take: in your view, add a remote link along with a div to receive the returned content. Create a .js.erb file named the same as your controller action, a partial that the .js.erb file renders back to your view, and your controller action to handle the remote call.  You may have to add a route that matches the controller#action to your new action.

Then set up your page with a div loading its content from a partial.  the partial will get reloaded during the ajax call. This assumes your controller is named sort and your action is album_select.

```
<div id="panels">
  <div id="dynamicLoadingPanel">
    <%=render :partial=>'album_select'%>
  </div>
  <%=link_to 'link text', :url=>'/sort/album_select/params', :remote=>'true', :id=>'navButton'%>
</div>
```

Or use jquery and an onclick event for your link:

```
  $("#navButton").bind('click',function(){
    //post to the controller/action/params
    $.post("/sort/album_select?album=100");
  });
```

In your controller

```
 def album_select
      @variables_for_your_view

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
      end
 # or use the new respond_with(@variables), and make sure to declare respond_to in your controller after the class definition
 end
```

In your album_select.js.erb file

```
$("#dynamicLoadingPanel").html("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>"album_select")%>");
```

maybe throw an alert('works!'); in here as well to make sure everything is linking up...I find it hard to debug the jquery in the .js.erb files.  Double check quotes, javascript escaping, and other easy to miss javascript errors.

In your partial

```
<p>info I just returned with new instance variables and fanciness</p>
```

Helps to have a javascript debugger on hand, and / or `tail -f` your log file.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to checkout [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) ([Demo](http://pjax.heroku.com/)). @dhh mentioned it in his keynote at RailsConf '11 and it really blows your mind! Thankfully he has also written a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pjax-rails) for Rails 3.1+, which integrates pjax into the asset pipeline.

I tested it with  Rails 3.0 app, and it really rocks. Your app feels faster and very responsive. Hopefully it will be integrated as default in some future version of Rails.
Unfortunately my current Rails project is still Rails 3.0, but I will implement pjax asap into it.

Comment: Thanks for introduction to pjax, faved the question, so that I can come back to this answer later :)

Answer (score 2):

For this, you need to use Ajax to do it. if you are using jQuery, then you can do something like this:

```
$("#navButton").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "/dynamic_panel.html",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#dynamicLoadingPanel").html(data);
    }
});
```

Then in rails, you have to create an action that response to dynamicPanel.html and render the content, you can render that content as a partial.

```
def dynamic_panel 
  render :partial => "dynamic_panel"
end
```

remember to add the route for dynamic_panel request. render :partial would make sure that it won't use the layout. Alternatively, you can just do render :layout=>false, so it will only render the content in dynamic_panel.html in the views.

Comment: Possible to add some code for the other pages involved?  Usually the syntax and function calls are what I need to see.  Thanks

Comment: This does not work.  for the url do I use the RoR routing path? There is an error that comes up in the jQuery because it stops there.

Comment: You might use (the) a rails ajax helper, try something like `...id="navButton" onclick="<%= remote_function(:url => {:controller => ..., :action => ...}, :update => "dynamicLoadingPanel") %>" ... ` This function is used by e.g. link_to_remote

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this answer will help you roll your own solution.

As Shanison said, it's an ajax call you're making. This answer lets you render normal, non-ajax pages on the same routes; this is generally a good idea - for example if somebody copies the url into a browser, they'll expect a full page and not a partial page

I'll be using jQuery here as well.

First make sure that the correct partial is rendered when the path is accessed with a format other than html (I used .js here):

categories/show.js.erb (only has the relevant part rendered):

```
<%= render 'categoryOne' %>
```

categories/show.html.erb (has the full page):

```
<!-- other page stuff -->
<div id="dynamicLoadingPanel">
<%= render 'categoryOne' %>
</div>
<!-- the rest of the page -->
```

Your page:

```
<%= link_to 'Content2', category_path(category),
            :class => 'ajax_link', :rel => 'dynamicLoadingPanel' %>
<div id="dynamicLoadingPanel"></div>
```

application.js:

```
$('a.ajax_link').click(function(e){
    // check that this element exists first
    if($('#' + $(this).attr('rel'))) {
        // stop the link from loading normally
        e.preventDefault();

        // load the .js version of the page into the div
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).load(this.href + '.js');
    }
});
```

What the javascript did was to make all `a`'s with the class `ajax_link` open its `href` in a DOM node where its `id` is the `a`'s `rel`.

With this code, you can make any link load in any id'd node on any path that has a .js view. And if the user's javascript is turned off/crashed or clicked in from an external link they'd get the normal page.

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def my_action
  end
end

# routes.rb
map '/my_action', 'my#my_action', as: 'my_action'# via: :get

# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= yield %>

# app/views/my/index.html.erb
<span id="navButton" class="button"><%= link_to "Content2", my_action_path, remote: true %></span>
<div id="dynamicLoadingPanel"></div>

# app/views/my/my_action.js.erb
$('#dynamicLoadingPanel').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(template: "my/my_action.html")) %>');

# app/views/my/my_action.html.erb
<p>My content here</p>
```